# Ajax Inside For Loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

In a chrome extension I am writing I need to validate some objects I have stored in localStorage against my server . For this I created a for loop that simply sends the data for each localstorage element and that needs to do something with the response . The code is something like this:

```
 for (var key in localStorage) {
        if (! some condition )
                      continue;

        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.response == 200) {
                do something with 'key' from the for loop
            }
        }
        };
        var url = BASE_PATH ;
        httpRequest.open("POST", url);
        httpRequest.send(some data);
                     }
```

However while debugging it seems that in the ajax response , the 'key' from the for loop isn't the key I need : I was expecting to get the same key from the for loop that matches each ajax call , what I got was the same key for all ajax calls . 
Am I doing something wrong or expecting something that isn't possible ? I thought that since the ajax is inside a closure function , the values are kept in memory or something of the sort .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: There is a ")" that shouldn't be there if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) && httpRequest.response == 200)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the actual Ajax call to a separate function:

```
function AjaxCall( key ) {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ((httpRequest.readyState === 4) && (httpRequest.response == 200)) {
      do something with 'key' from the for loop
    }
  };
  var url = BASE_PATH ;
  httpRequest.open("POST", url);
  httpRequest.send(some data);
}

for (var key in localStorage) {
  if ( some condition ) {    
    AjaxCall( key );
  }    
}
```

Reason is, that you are creating a closure with the function passed to `onreadystatechange`. All those functions point to the same `key` variable, which holds just one (the last) value for all Ajax calls, after the loop is finished.

When you create a separate function (like the `AjaxCall()` in my example), you create a different context for each call and hence all callbacks point to different keys.

Comment: As I said in the question, there is a ) that shouldn't be there. Besides, the "else" is not necessary, because if the continue is reached the code below won't be executed. However, good explanation.

Comment: Also, in your for loop, if you are not already using the hasOwnProperty method you may want to try it. This will prevent you from sending a property name or function name that is inherited from the Object type.

Comment: @jhorton: None of the native properties defined at `Object.prototype` are enumerable. It will be fine as long as no custom, enumerable properties are defined on the prototype.